# Export DataTable to Excel File in Webpage

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, export-to-excel

I have a DataTable with 50+ columns and 100000+ rows.I need to dump the whole DataTable values into an Excel file.Can anyone please help with the C# code in ASP.net.I need each column value to be in a cell.To be precise,I need the exact looking copy of DataTable in an Excel File.Please help.

Thanks,
 Kiran

Answer (score 1):

[Link for Export Excel](http://[http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/406704/Export-DataTable-to-Excel-with-Formatting-in-Cshar][1])

Have a look at the `ExporttoExcel` function of this example. It would help you.

Comment: But my data is 140 columns and 100000 rows. i am getting out of memory exception. The main Issue is that my server configuration is 2 GB and it works well with 4 GB. Ram is the limitation.  My client cant increase the RAM. Any suggestion

Answer (score 0):

you can call this method, just pass in your DataTable:

```
public static void DumpExcel(DataTable dataTable)
    {
        using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage())
        {
            ExcelWorksheet worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("DataTable");

            worksheet.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(dataTable, true);

            for (int i = 1; i <= dataTable.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                worksheet.Column(i).AutoFit();

                if (dataTable.Columns[i - 1].DataType == System.Type.GetType("System.DateTime"))
                {
                    worksheet.Column(i).Style.Numberformat.Format = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern;
                }
            }

            HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;  filename=table.xlsx");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(package.GetAsByteArray());
            HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    public void ExportToExcel(string strFileName, DataTable dt)
    {
        try
        {
            if (dt != null && dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                GridView gv = new GridView();
                gv.DataSource = dt;
                gv.DataBind();
                ExportToExcel(strFileName, gv);
            }
            else
            {
                BindScript(this.Page, "excelError", "alert('No Data to Generate Excel !')");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            BindScript(this.Page, "excelError", "alert('Some error occured " + ex.Message + "')");
        }
    }

    private void ExportToExcel(string strFileName, GridView gv)
    {
        try
        {
            if (gv.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                //Page page = new Page();
                //HtmlForm form = new HtmlForm();
                //Response.ClearContent();
                //Response.Buffer = true;
                //Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + strFileName);
                //Response.ContentType = "application/excel";
                ////System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
                //StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
                //HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
                //form.Controls.Add(gv);
                //page.Controls.Add(form);
                ////form.RenderControl(htw);
                //HttpContext.Current.Server.Execute(page, sw, true);
                //Response.Write(sw.ToString());
                //Response.Flush();
                //Response.End();

                StringWriter tw = new StringWriter();
                HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(tw);

                //Get the HTML for the control.
                gv.RenderControl(hw);
                //Write the HTML back to the browser.
                //Response.ContentType = application/vnd.ms-excel;
                Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
                Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + strFileName);
                EnableViewState = false;
                Response.Write(tw.ToString());
                Response.End();
            }
            else
            {
                BindScript(this.Page, "excelError", "alert('No Data to Generate Excel !')");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            BindScript(this.Page, "excelError", "alert('Some error occured " + ex.Message + "')");
        }
    }
```